# Mocha isn't displaying any details for failed tests

Tags: node.js, sails.js, mocha.js

I'm migrating an app from Sails.js v0.12 to v1.0, which includes upgrading mocha from ^3.5.0 to ^5.2.0.  I assume that is the root of the issue, but I can't seem to find a fix.

Before, when a test failed, there would be a summary of the error at the end of the mocha reporter output: the specific assertion that failed, file name, line number, error message, etc.  Now, the reporter is coloring the *it* block in red, but no additional details are show.

I've tried changing the reporter in mocha.opts, which works for the actual execution output, but nothing is enabling the summary at the end. What am I missing?

```
// ./test/integration/models/User.test.js

describe('User', () => {

  describe('find()', () => {
    it('should return an array of users', () => {
      return User.find()
      .then((users) => {

        users.should.be.a('array');
        true.should.be.false;  // No problems if this is removed

      });
    });
  });

});
```

In the console:

```
> node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha test/lifecycle.test.js test/integration/**/*.test.js


√ OtherModel method() should do something: 17ms
1) User find() should return an array of users
'Done.'
PS C:\repos\myproject>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out that Mocha is fine and my test definitions are fine, I had simply fixed a totally different migration issue incorrectly. Since version 4, [mocha will no longer automatically kill itself](https://boneskull.com/mocha-v4-nears-release/#mochawontforceexit) when it thinks all tests are complete.  This means that one of these two options must be used:

1. Add `--exit` to mocha.opts or to wherever the command is called
2. Run `process.exit()` in your test suite's JavaScript

I tried the second option by adding `process.exit()` to the `after()` block in my test bootstrap file.  **This is a bad idea and resulted in the confusing behavior above.**

To solve my issue, I removed my changes to the `after()` block and added `--exit` to mocha.opts.  Thanks to Dhruv Choudhary for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: The `--exit` allows you to use the pre-version 4. is there a way to avoid that and fix the problem?

Answer (score 3):

you can use done callback. The first strategy suggested in the mocha documentation is using the ‘done’ callback. This is an extra argument to the callback in the it . You call it after the last assertion in your test.

I have seen many people using done() method in wrong way. for example, look at below code,

```
describe('User', () => {

  describe('find()', () => {
    it('should return an array of users', (done) => {
      return User.find()
      .then((users) => {

        users.should.be.a('array');
        true.should.be.false;  // No problems if this is removed
        done();

      });
    });
  });

});
```

The above test will work fine and show the test passing, But calling done() in the same then callback is a bad idea because The above code works well until your expectation fails, you might get error like
[image]

The above failure is not very useful . If we want to utilize the mocha’s error we shouldn’t call done() from the same then() callback. See the below test

```
describe('User', () => {

    describe('find()', () => {
        it('should return an array of users', (done) => {
            return User.find()
                .then((users) => {

                    users.should.be.a('array');
                    true.should.be.false;
                })
                .then(() => done(), done)
                .catch((error) => {
                    done(error);

                });
        });
    });
});
```

do not forget to wrap your error with catch block.
Now see the difference in the mocha’s failure message with actual and expected..

Comment: You're right that the .catch() block works, but my older mocha tests display useful error messages without adding that extra code. Was that changed in mocha v5, for some reason?

Comment: Also, I tried out your code. Passing the error to done() doesn't seem to have any effect, in my test environment.  The best workaround I've found so far is `.catch(console.error);`

Comment: I think it is not related to mocha version (not very sure though, have a look to the fix in latest mocha version: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/3226). It could be issue with the way you handle the promise as older (pre 2013) promise libraries 'swallowed' unhandled promise rejections you have not handled yourself. This has not been the case now, you have to handle it with catch block.

Comment: That issue page is a big help, thanks. It looks like my trouble are rooted in adding `process.exit();` to mocha's `after()` block in an attempt to cleanly exit without `--exit`. I guess I need to put it somewhere else...

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding done callback to your test case .

```
describe('User', () => {

  describe('find()', () => {
    it('should return an array of users', (done) => {
      return User.find()
      .then((users) => {

        users.should.be.a('array');
        true.should.be.false;  // No problems if this is removed
        done();

      });
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: I have tried that, actually. In mocha, you're meant to either use the done() function or return a promise, but never both. It just throws an error, but still only results in red text, no details.